# Typescript generic converting functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I was playing around with generics in typescript v4.0.2 and came across this oddity. Why does the compiler complain that `T` is not a `string` after I have narrowed it as such?

```
function foo<T>(arg: T): T {
    if (typeof arg === "string") {
        return "hello"
    }

    return arg
}
```

The error is:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.
```

Comment: What if you call it as `foo<"bar">("bar")`?

Comment: Or more likely, `const bar = "bar"; foo(bar);`

Comment: I have looked at the typescript handbook and there doesn't see to be an easy way to do what I am trying to do? Because from a JS perspective "bar" is only of type string

Comment: TS types are a lot more detailed than what JavaScript's `typeof x` will give you at runtime, so I'm not sure that "`"bar"` is only a type of `string`" is a fruitful line of reasoning.  If what you are trying to do is return `string` when `T extends string` and `T` otherwise, then you will end up needing either conditional types or overloads, each of which has drawbacks.  I wonder what your use cases are though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function signature:

```
foo<T>(arg: T): T
```

Returns the same type as its argument. This means if you pass in the string `"Sebastian"`, you expect to get `"Sebastian"` back, not just any string. But the way you have written this function, it would return `"hello"` instead, which has a different string literal type.

To support this logic, I think [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) are what you want. You would create a special call signature just for strings that returns strings, then a generic call signature that handles all other argument types.

```
function foo(arg: string): "hello"
function foo<T>(arg: T): T
function foo<T>(arg: T): T | "hello" {
    if (typeof arg === "string") {
        return "hello"
    }

    return arg
}

const a = foo('testing')     // type: "hello"
const b = foo(123)           // type: 123
const c = foo(123 as number) // type: number
const d = foo({ abc: 123 })  // type: { abc: 123 }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDATgcwFyIDOUWMYOAlAQEQAWApgDaNzUBQoksCyqAPABUAfJlwEBVRAI7ho8JCjiCR2fFMkDEAH0R0mLaogDebRGcQxgiNFACeAB3pwrqxAF4Pu4qXLUKx03MgrHooECwkPWZWQLMAXzZYxBCwiMRVNgS2CARidPdedAByKHpiMhwi-wB6asQ7RxoGaPYcsDyAIwLFNABGACYAZhq6hvoCAcHs3KhECG7UPqH0wkQwEABbDvosEfqHcbXN7axp9tmAEwX0I3SOiAnluL2xgluMe8fBxASgA)

Comment: If the argument is a union including a string literal it will give a badly typed result.  e.g.,  `foo(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "bar" : 2)` returns `"bar" | 2` when you probably want `"hello" | 2`. Personally I'd have just one call signature, `foo<T>(arg: T): T extends string ? "hello" : T;`.  You can still use the `foo<T>(arg: T): T | "hello"` implementation signature, though.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/oN9b9m)

Comment: Thanks, it is definitely the overloading that I wanted. Though more specifically I went with the following: 

`function foo(arg: string): string; function foo<T>(arg: T): T;`

Comment: @jcalz Indeed. I was thinking that mixing an unconstrained generic in one overload where the other overload had no generic might get a bit weird.